# []+(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{})+(-~{}-~{})

Tags: javascript

How can `[]+(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{})+(-~{}-~{})` be equals to `"42"` in javascript?

Sorry for the title, but it can make it easier for other people to find the post. (I saw it mentioned in a forum)

Solved :
[] will convert the expression to a String.
-~{} = -1
So
-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{} = 4
-~{}-~{} = 2

The rest is String concatenation

Comment: Without going through all the math, the basics is that javascript does some [weird stuff](http://wtfjs.com/) when you try to add/subtract different types together.

Comment: Yeah, this coupled with `~{} -> -1` will explain the given expression.

Comment: It just has to do with empty arrays and empty objects equaling some numbers when you flip the bits and start adding them together

Comment: Does `valueOf()` and `toString()` makes to difference? Maybe something easier to begin with :  `[]  + {}` = [Object Object] `{} + []` = 0

Comment: Note that in the end it's doing `[] + 4 + 2`. `[] + 4` is `"4"` so then + becomes concatenation, i.e. `"4" + 2` = `"42"`

Comment: This is different question, the other one does not contain ~{}! This is question about similar feature, but it is different. Especially search for ~{} would find this one, but not the other

Comment: I've understood the question I posted in the comment. But still, If someone could provide a step by step explanation for this one...